# Bitbucket Cloud : Conditionally skip stage or step using variables

Tags: bitbucket-cloud

We have several stages consisting of one or more steps. We would like ability to define if a stage should be executed based on condition declared as workspace or repository variable.

Looked at the schema but condition does not let us use variables as intended. https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/intellij-bitbucket-references-plugin/raw/master/src/main/resources/schemas/bitbucket-pipelines.schema.json

```
pipelines:
  default:
     - stage:          
         name: Deploy to QA
         deployment: qa
         condition: ${QA_STAGE_ENABLED} == "true"
         trigger: manual
         steps:
           - step:
```

condition: ${QA_STAGE_ENABLED} == "true" is what is being recommended. At the moment the only way to skip a stage is to comment it out in bitbucket-pipelines.yaml file which is not the most pleasant experience.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Pipeline's `condition` clause only works for `changesets` that too for just `includePath` condition as of now.
If you want to use a variable or an artifact derived value to skip an step, you can implement a bash-style `IF` condition as the first step of your `script`, it will execute the step and mark it as done but you can skip any lines of code you do not want to execute as part of this step, for example:

```
pipelines:
  default:
     - stage:          
         name: Deploy to QA
         deployment: qa
         trigger: manual
         steps:
           - step:
            name: Deploy
            script:
              - if [[ ${QA_STAGE_ENABLED} != "true" ]]; then printf 'QA Stage deployment is not enabled, exiting.'; exit; fi
              - sh ./deploy-app.sh
```

Comment: This is the only way currently but it's not the most effective way, as this step would be run after the container for the step has been created hence wasting time in the step. Moreover a stage could be made up of multiple steps, how do we completely skip all the steps under a stage and move to another stage? The only way I know of is to exit with 0 on each step so build doesn't fail but steps are skipped. Atlassian should consider my proposed solution so people using bitbucket pipeline have effective way to deal with this use-case.

Comment: Unfortunately they are real slow in implementing useful features. However as a workaround you can also use a file in your repo and before this stage have it updated with some random values, in this way you can have `includePath` available for you in the conditionsets.